# Как правильно добавить функцию удаления?

Tags: java, android

После полезных комментариев в чате, было добавлена функция удаления:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    List<ImageUpload> imageUploads;
    int resource;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<ImageUpload> imageUploads, int resource) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUploads = imageUploads;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View gridView = (View) convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            gridView = new View(context);
            if (imageUploads.get(position).getOutputMetadata().getFilename().equals("null")) {
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_upload_default, null);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.iv_upload);
                imageView.setImageResource(resource);
            } else {
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_upload, null);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.iv_upload);
                ImageView closeView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.photo_close_btn);
                final ProgressWheel progress = (ProgressWheel) gridView.findViewById(R.id.loader_photo);
                ImageUpload mobile = imageUploads.get(position);
                if (imageUploads.get(position).isLoadImage())
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(StringUtil.URLADS_THUMBLER_RESIZE + 150 + "x" + 150 + "/" + StringUtil.URLADS_THUMBLER_IMAGE + mobile.getOutputMetadata().getFilename())
                            .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError() {

                                }
                            });
                else {
                    File f = new File(imageUploads.get(position).getPath());
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(f)
                            .into(imageView);
                }
                closeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        imageUploads.remove(position);
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        return gridView;
    }
```

Но появилась новая проблема, после того как нажимаю на кнопку удалить выбивает ошибку:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
```

И указывает на эту строчку...
imageUploads.remove(position);

Comment: повесте onClickListener на photo_close_btn, и удаляйте по клику элемент из imageUploads, после чего делайте notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: пишу что то подобное не получается((
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            list.remove(position);
        }
    });

Comment: @metalurgus нужно ли будет менять мой адаптер добавляя в него ViewHolder?

Comment: Что конкретно пишете, что именно значит ваше *не получается*? При чем тут вообще ViewHolder?

Comment: @metalurgus написал как вы мне посоветовали, присвоить id onClickListener после чего удалять элемент из imageUploads.
комментарием выше написал код, как пробовал это делать. Подскажите пожалуйста что не так? а про ViewHolder спрашиваю, потому что дополнительно смотрел примеры.

Comment: Вы мне сначала расскажите, чего вы решили, что там "что-то не так"?

Comment: @metalurgus выделяет ошибки красным... Возможно не в тот участок кода вставляю

Comment: и, что за ошибки? Давайте не тянуть кота за хвост, и вы сразу расскажете? я уже 3 комментария написал в попыках добиться от вас информации\

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45915/discussion-between-inkognito-and-metalurgus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите у вашего `photo_close_btn` `OnClickListener`, в котором удаляйте из `imageUploads` нужный элемент: `imageUploads.remove(position);`, и не забудьте после этого вызвать `notyfyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: возможно сделать так, чтоб он удалял выбранный элемент, а не в порядке убывания?)